Show that if $A(m, n)$ is nonsingular, then ${m + n \choose n}$ is even
The problem statement from Exercise 1(a) of chapter 6 of Algebraic Combinatorics by Richard Stanley: Let $A(m, n)$ be the adjacency matrix (over $\mathbb{R}$) of the Hasse diagram of $L(m, n)$, the poset of all partitions contained within an $m \times n$ box. Show that if $A(m, n)$ is non-singular, then ${m + n \choose n}$ is even.
My approach: I tried to prove the contrapositive, that if ${m + n \choose n}$ is odd, then $A(m, n)$ is singular. I first realized that there is a trivial pairing of partitions contained in $L(m, n)$, namely by considering the "inverse" partition; in particular, for any partition $\lambda$ in $L(m, n)$, if we color in the squares of $\lambda$ black, then the remaining $mn - |\lambda|$ squares form the corresponding inverse partition (though upside down if you draw it out). Since ${m + n \choose n}$ is the number of partitions in $L(m, n)$ (including the empty partition, so the partition $\langle n^m \rangle$, $m$ parts of size $n$, is also paired up).
Since we assumed that ${m + n \choose n}$ is odd, we know that there must exist a partition that is its own inverse. I was hoping to use the existence of such a partition to show that $A(m, n)$ must have a zero eigenvalue, but I have been stuck for a few hours now. Any hints or help would be appreciated!
Other notes: I also realized that a self-inverse partition must be of the form $\lambda = (\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n)$, where $\lambda_i + \lambda_{m - i + 1} = n$. So if $m$ is odd, then $\lambda_k$ is the middle part of the partition, for $k = m + 1/2$. Then $2\lambda_k = n,$ so $n$ must also be even.
